# Connect to Azure SQL server via AAD Authentication using EF Core

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, entity-framework-core, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-server

Azure SQL servers support AAD authentication, and I want my applications to connect to SQL server using AAD authentication and not SQL server admin credentials. I am using EF core to connect to SQL, how do I enable EF Core to use AAD authentication.

My application is deployed in Azure App Service and it has MSI extension enabled, so I am looking forward to using `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` for getting the token from AAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Connect to Azure SQL server via AAD Authentication using EF Core

If your project platform is **.netcore**, it is `not supported` currently.  I also find the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/13660) on the github.

Or you could refer to this [blog](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/configuring-aad-authentication-to-azure-sql-databases) or another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130105/entity-framework-connection-to-sql-azure-db-using-access-token/43133661#43133661).

> so I am looking forward to using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication for getting the token from AAD

You could get the demo code from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication)
 You could get the demo code from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication)

```
 var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
 string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Update:**

Thanks for AlejandroC sharing, it is supported in .NET Core 2.2 Preview 1, for more information please refer [.NET Core 2.2 Preview 1 - August 22, 2018](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/preview/2.2.0-preview1.md)

Comment: I have another application where I have ADO.NET running on ADO.NET Framework 4.6. I am able to inject the access token in the DB Connection but there doesn't seem to be any mechanism in .NET Core.

Comment: "f your project platform is .netcore, it is not supported currently." - I got my answer, thanks.

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 Preview 1 includes it https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/preview/2.2.0-preview1.md