# Azure Functions runtime 2 - SQL Connections using SqlClient

Tags: c#, function, azure, azure-functions

Unable to use the .Net SqlClient with the runtime 2. Getting the following error about missing references:

> 2018-04-09T13:48:51.172 [Information] Compilation failed.
>
> 2018-04-09T13:48:58.071 [Information] Script for function
>   'SqlExecutorActivity' changed. Reloading.
>
> 2018-04-09T13:48:58.363 [Error] run.csx(29,5): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name 'SqlConnectionStringBuilder' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 2018-04-09T13:48:58.376 [Error] run.csx(29,68): error CS1069: The type
>   name 'SqlConnectionStringBuilder' could not be found in the namespace
>   'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that
>   assembly.
>
> 2018-04-09T13:48:58.387 [Error] run.csx(71,28): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name 'AzureServiceTokenProvider' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 2018-04-09T13:48:58.396 [Error] run.csx(78,27): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 2018-04-09T13:48:58.417 [Error] run.csx(83,30): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name 'SqlCommand' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
#r "System.Data"
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public static async Task<string> Run(string requestData, TraceWriter log)
{
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MaintQueueData>(requestData);
    log.Info($"Doing work in Server {data.Server}.");
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder["Server"] = data.Server;
    builder["Initial Catalog"] = data.Database;
    builder["Connect Timeout"] = 30;
    builder["Trusted_Connection"] = true;
    builder["Integrated Security"] = false;

    log.Info($"{builder.ConnectionString} ... HAHA no passwords br0ski!");

    var token = (String)null;
    var result = (String)null;

    try
    {
        token = await ADAuthentication.GetSqlTokenAsync();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        string error = $"Failed to authenticate with AAD: {e.Message}";
        log.Error($"{error}");
        return error;
    }

    try
    {
        result = await ExecuteInSql(builder.ConnectionString, token, data.Query);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        string error = $"Failed to execute SQL: {e.Message}";
        log.Error($"{error}");
        return error;
    }

    log.Info($"Query Complete: {data.Query}, Results: {result}");
    return $"Query Complete: {data.Query}, Results: {result}";
}
public static class ADAuthentication
{
    const String SqlResource = "https://database.windows.net/";

    public static Task<String> GetSqlTokenAsync()
    {
        var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        return provider.GetAccessTokenAsync(SqlResource);
    }
}

private static async Task<String> ExecuteInSql(String connectionString, String token, String Query)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.AccessToken = token;
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        String text = Query; 
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            var result = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
            return result as String;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code in `httptrigger` and got the same problem with you.

However, I noticed that when the runtime is "**beta**", it load `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`package.

If your project platform is **.netcore**, **[it is not supported connect to Azure SQL server via AAD Authentication.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407321/connect-to-azure-sql-server-via-aad-authentication-using-ef-core)**

So, I suggest you could try to use runtime 1 of azure function to achieve what you want.

> Azure Functions runtime 2.0 is in preview, and currently not all features of Azure Functions are supported.

Also, you could use Active Directory password authentication to connect.

To connect to a database using integrated authentication and an Azure AD identity, the Authentication keyword in the database connection string must be set to Active Directory Integrated. The following C# code sample uses ADO .NET.

```
string ConnectionString =
@"Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated; Initial Catalog=testdb;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Comment: Pls clarify if you got the SQL connection bit to work with runtime2?

Comment: Yes, when I test your code in httptrigger with runtime2 get the same error with you. But I found that when I tested it in blobtrigger, it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. Downgraded to .net461 and published from visual studio and it's now working.