# Azure AD Authentication for Entity Framework 6 in DB first approach

Tags: azure, entity-framework, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-server

I am trying to configure the connection string to use Azure AD Authentication. I am able to connect to SQL Server using standard SQL Connection with Azure AD Authentication. My application uses Entity Framework 6 DataBase first approach. I have override the DbContext to generate the connection string at run time. Is it possible to configure the Azure AD AUthentication for EF 6 Data Base First approach.

I am getting keyword metadata not supported when trying to connect with standard SQL connection as my model is build using Database first approach. If am removing metadata from connection string then am getting Untintional Code First exception.

How can I configure EF 6 DataBase first approach with Azure AD Authentication

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ref this post: [Entity Framework connection to SQL Azure DB using access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130105/entity-framework-connection-to-sql-azure-db-using-access-token).

I don't if he uses the Database-first model, I think it's helpful for you to configure the AAD access token.